# How to specify COBOL copybook in Sqoop + OpenSource Syncsort

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, mainframe, vsam, syncsort-dmx-h

I'm trying to import some VSAM files from Mainframe into Hive.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_3

I found out that Sqoop 1.4.6 includes Syncsort as an Open-Source contrib. I went through the documentation and it is not clear to me whether I can include a COBOL copybook or not in this version.

Does anyone tried to do this or know an alternative?

Comment: Well, it looks from your link that sqoop supports sequential "text" files in a PDS. So. Forget Sqoop for VSAM, would I. I'm not at all sure what you are trying to ask in your second paragraph. I'm sure that whatever you do mean, if it is not covered in the documentation, it is unlikely to work by magic. Bear in mind that "tell me some tools to stuff VSAM into Hadoop" is an off-topic question here. You have to find a tool, have a problem with it, then ask. And maybe wait a bit.

Comment: Sqoop + syncsort commercial version includes functionality to ingest a VSAM specifying its copybook (according to their sales speech).

And the same goes for the open source version. But when I read the documentation, I can't find an specific section that describes those features. That is why I am confused and asking this.

Comment: The link you provide supplies no evidence of that. A VSAM data set cannot exist within a PDS (nor PDSE). The link only talks about PDS. That in itself is a bit curious, because usually you wouldn't have multiple and e"files" within a PDS. Anyway, terminology-wise, they would be "members". Going down the "hierarchy" of a data set name, would "look at bit like" files being in a PDS. Perhaps the author of the documentation is short of a clue or two. Are you using the commercial version? Ask under your support contract. Else there's probably somewhere more direct to post the question.

Comment: I'm really not sure the documentation knows what it is talking about. Ignoring the reference to PDS, it doesn't necessarily preclude a VSAM data set (but still would seem to have the "text" limitation). If the consumer was the Syncsort thing, then that would be the place to ask.

Comment: I would be surprised if the Cobol was available (that is why sync-sort charges mega bucks). Even if there is a cobol option, most Cobol files will be binary so the Cobol option will not do you much good, you would still need mainframe programmers to convert the files to Text.

Comment: Finally I would hope there is an option to download sequential files as well. PDS's are not directories. PDS's are use to hold Cobol Copybooks, Cobol Programs, JCL, Rexx programs etc. That is great if you want to analyze the Cobol programs but not much good if you want to analyze data.